# Fallo en el menú al cargar el load en un div

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap

Tengo en una aplicación web un menú con `bootstrap`. Al pinchar en un botón se carga un `load` en un `div` y me deja de funcionar el menú.

La función javascript:

```
<script>
funtion carga_div(){
document.getElementById('carga').load('cargaClase.php');
}
</script>
```

Código del body:

```
<div id='carga'> </div>

<button  onclick="carga_div();
 return false" id="aceptar" name="aceptar" class="btnAceptar">Aceptar</button>
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "_me deja de funcionar el menú_"?¿Y cuál es el contenido de cargaClase.php? Puede que algún elemento que venga de cargaClase esconda el menú pero es imposible saberlo con el código incluído en la pregunta (que a primera vista parece correcto).

Comment: Gracias por contestar. El menú tiene desplegables y cuando se carga el load deja de salir los desplegables y ya no me redirige a las páginas que indico en el menú. El código de cargaClase solo tiene una tabla con datos.

Comment: ¿Hay algún error en la consola de JS?¿o algún estilo que se aplique y superponga la tabla sobre el menú?¿Se puede ver la página en algún sitio?

Comment: lo que recomendaria es que uses el Developer tools del browser, al cual accedes con F12, he inspecciones al html generar cuando se inyecta el php en el div, de esta forma podrias analizar que estilos se aplican en la pagina. Algo que no ash comentado si este php contiene javascript o si defines los tag html y body, proque si lo hace esto podria causar problemas, valida que el php yo renderize la tabla unicamente

Comment: Hola, tengo los tag html y body porque llamo a una función javascript que me transforma la tabla. Tendrá algo que ver con eso?

Comment: Te recomiendo que publique un ejemplo más completo de tu código porque con la información que brindas actualmante es imposible darle una respuesta a tu pregunta

Comment: Hola @Adamisa podríamos ver el contenido de ese `php` que estas cargando con  `.load()`

Comment: Ya lo conseguí. Tenia html dentro del PHP y estaba dando problemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se resolvió al quitar los elementos de html que había en el archivo PHP cargado.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que el menú viene dentro del nuevo php? o sea que es reemplazado? los menús dinámicos como estos dependen de acciones que son asignadas a los elementos, si el elemento es reemplazado después de cargar la página la acción que había sido asignada se pierde. Quizá tienes que re-activar el menú después de cargar la nueva página.

Comment: Gracias por contestar pero no tengo el menú dentro del php